# jQuery: Check If All Form-Fields Are Populated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I am using **jQuery** + **CoffeeScript** + **Pug** (+ **Bootstrap 4**):

I have a `form`, which looks like this, but with many (ten or more) items, so *individually* checking them is hard:

```
form(method="post")

  .form-group
    label Title
    input.form-control(name="title" type="text")

  .form-group
    label Description
    textarea.form-control(name="description")

  ...
```

I'd like to check if all `input` fields are **populated**, each time the user types something. The goal is to decide whether a `#save`-button should be **shown** or **hidden**. This `#save`-button should only be shown when the `form` is *fully* populated.

My first attempt was:

```
$(window).on 'keydown', (keydown) ->
  ...
```

I tried to to apply jQuery's `each` loop, then I tried to use jQuery's `.val()`-method. But I didn't come to a solution. Maybe you can help.

Thank you.

**Edit 2:**

```
formElements = $ 'form input[type="text"], form input[type="number"], form textarea'

formFilled = ->
  filled = true
  formElements.each ->
    if $(this).val().length is 0
      filled = false
  filled

formElements.on 'keyup', (keyup) ->
  keyup.preventDefault()
  if formFilled()
    save.show()
  else
    save.hide()
```

Somebody who knows what the coffee-script compiler makes of this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't use `$(window).on('keydown')`, simply because that will trigger any time the user presses a key, regardless of where on the screen they are. You'll want to narrow it down to form inputs.

If the form is entirely text fields and text areas, you can do this:

```
//Function will return a true or false
function formIsComplete() {

    var isComplete = true;

    //For every text input and textarea in the form
    $('form input[type="text"], form textarea').each(function() {
        $t = $(this);
        if ($t.val().length == 0) {
            //Found an empty input
            isComplete = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    //No empty inputs found
    return isComplete;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    $saveBtn = $('#save');

    //Add 'keyup' event to all form text inputs and textareas
    $('form input[type="text"], form textarea').on('keyup', function() {
        if (formIsComplete()) {
            //All fields have values
            $saveBtn.show();
        } else {
            //Something was empty
            $saveBtn.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** I've changed the event from `keydown` to `keyup`, only because `keydown` triggers before the value of the input is changed. This means that when a user enters the first character, the keydown event will still see the input as empty.

Comment: @Timo No problem. Let me know how it works. I'll add some comments to explain the process.

Comment: could you revise the code a little? I mean, the button is shown already when I type something in the first input field. :-(

Comment: thanks for the hint! using keyup instead of keydown !!! :D but it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: Are you sure you're implementing it correctly? Please see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dbctdLb/) - I edited my answer to fix an issue, but this was prior to your comment saying that it wasn't working. Please make sure you're using the latest!

Comment: Hey @Santi, I did some code testing and have maybe the solution to the problem: the `formElements.each ->` runs twice. One time with the "right" credentials and one time as null and zero. Any thought on that? Thanks!

Comment: Ah unfortunately I'm not as familiar with CofeeScript as i should be, and so I'm not sure how much further I can help. Sorry, best of luck moving forward!

Comment: so thank you. I will tell you if it works... one day :D